# How to animate world properties color?

Tags: keyframes, color, world

[image]

[image]

Hi, I would like to animate my world color but not sure how i can do it. In the first keyframe, I would like my world color to be pitch black. However, in the 40th keyframe I would like my world color to be a light grey. How do I do that? Thanks!

Comment: if you go into the Shader Editor / World mode, you can keyframe the Color of the Background node

Comment: moonboots heheh youre truly a savior hehe im pretty new to blender thanks!